# Android send custom parameter on AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Hi all by this below method i can send any custom parameters on that without problem. now i want to change this method to AsyncTask class as name `LongOperation`but i can dont know how to send `getRequestFromServer` method parameters to `AsyncTask`

my method is:

```
public static void getRequestFromServer(final long lastID, final int count,
                                        final ContentResolver cr){
```

and i want to have like with this:

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<final long lastID, final int count,
                                            final ContentResolver cr> {
```

Comment: use `Constructor` for sending those values

Comment: try this new LongOperation(longID,count,cr).execute();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    long lastID;
    int count;
    ContentResolver cr;

    public LongOperation(final long lastID, final int count,
                                    final ContentResolver cr){
        this.lastID = lastID;
        this.count = count;
        this.cr = cr;
    }
```

To use it:

```
new LongOperation(LAST_ID,COUNT,CR).execute();
```

Comment: for parameters on AsyncTask i get this error: `Syntax error on token "lastID", invalid Dimensions`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to pass parameter to doInBackground method like this

```
  private static class MyTaskParams {
    long lastID;
    int count;
    ContentResolver cr ;

    MyTaskParams(long id, int count, ContentResolver cr) {
        this.lastID; = id;
        this.count = count;
        this.cr = cr;
    }
    }
      @Override
        protected void doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) {
           long lastID= params[0].lastID;
            int  count= params[0].count;
            ContentResolver cr= params[0].cr;
            ...
        }
```

And to call your Asynctaks you have to write following code: new LongOperation().execute(passing);

Comment: This does not answer the question. Where are the parameters requested in the question ? long lastID, int count, ContentResolver cr ?